# Anyway to just run the code in the ide window from pressing F5 in visual studio code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I keep getting this in my python terminal :

[Keeps Mapping to Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYAE0.jpg)

I just want to just run the code itself in the python shell (am using Visual Studio Code as the IDE) .. how do I remove the path from running

Answer (score 0):

from the python shell, you could simply enter:

```
>>> execfile('path_to_file.py')
```

Comment: can it just run without the execfile command .. I'm using vscode as the IDE